# How to use thymeleaf conditions - if - elseif - else

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a little problem, I must return a different choice of a select into a `td` using thymeleaf, I try the next sentence:

```html
<td style="white-space: nowrap">
    <span th:class="${linea.estado}? 'label label-success' : 'label label-danger' : 'label label-warning'"
          th:text="${linea.estado}? #{label.glineas.estado.iniciado} : #{label.glineas.estado.finalizado} : #{label.glineas.estado.configurado}">
    </span>
</td>
```

But I have a problem because the condition give me a big failure because is impossible to parse the expression. With only two conditions (iniciado and finalizado) there aren't problem, but I need to get the correct label for the select in my form.

Anybody knows the correct sentence to use a if elseif else sentence with thymeleaf?

2.0 Now I am trying to solve this problem with the next:

```html
<td style="white-space: nowrap">
    <span th:if="${linea.estado} == 'Iniciado'" class="label label-success" th:text="#{label.glineas.estado.iniciado}"></span>
    <span th:if="${linea.estado} == 'Finalizado'" class="label label-danger" th:text="#{label.glineas.estado.finalizado}"></span>
    <span th:if="${linea.estado} == 'Configuracion'" class="label label-warning" th:text="#{label.glineas.estado.configurado}"></span>
</td>
```

The solution is perfect, now all works properly. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You conditional operator contains 3 results. It should have 2 like this.

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

In your situation. I assume `linea.estado` is a `boolean` value

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap">
    <span th:class="${linea.estado} ? 'label label-success' : 'label label-danger'" 
        th:text="${linea.estado}? #{label.glineas.estado.iniciado} : #{label.glineas.estado.finalizado}">
    </span>
</td>
```

If you want 3 values to be output and given that the `linea.estado` is a string which may contain `'WARN', 'DANGER', 'INFO'` then you can do something like this.

```
<span th:class="'label label-' + ((${linea.estado} == 'SUCCESS') ? 'success' : (${linea.estado} == 'DANGER') ? 'danger' : 'warning')"                   
      th:text="...">
</span>
```

But the **cleaner solution will be** something like this

```
<span th:if="${linea.estado} == 'SUCCESS'" class="label label-success" th:text="#{label.glineas.estado.iniciado}"></span>
<span th:if="${linea.estado} == 'DANGER'" class="label label-danger" th:text="#{label.glineas.estado.finalizado}"></span>
<span th:if="${linea.estado} == 'WARN'" class="label label-warning" th:text="#{label.glineas.estado.configurado}"></span>
```

Or using `Switch` as mentioned by *Patrick LC*

- *be aware of syntax errors, as I didnt test any codes on runtime*

Comment: I know that you can only have 2 conditions, for that i was asked for an alternative. Linea.estado is not a boolen, thats the problem.

Comment: I will try that solution, because i have problem with the switch, thank you.

Comment: Ok now it works, i was a problem with my variables, with linea.idestado it works.... thanks for all

Answer (score 5):

I think the solution is to use the switch statement, from Thymeleaf [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#switch-statements):

```
<div th:switch="${user.role}">
  <p th:case="'admin'">User is an administrator</p>
  <p th:case="#{roles.manager}">User is a manager</p>
  <p th:case="*">User is some other thing</p>
</div>
```

There isn't any other structure to use in Thymeleaf, although you could use th:if/th:unless. Check [this](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/quot-lt-c-choose-gt-lt-c-when-gt-quot-How-to-do-in-thymeleaf-td4026125.html) thread in the thymeleaf forum.

Comment: I will try that option, i read before about that option but i have the dude aboout the integration in a table.

Answer (score 5):

I need else if but all my condition are not so simple that th:switch="${user.role} can works, so I do this:

```
<div th:switch="true">
    <p th:case="${product.price} == '849'"> Beautiful Goat</p>
    <p th:case="false"> Magnificent Goat</p>
    <p th:case="'Whatever things I want to do with my else if'"> Goat</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

For next time if you want `if - elsif -else` you can do:
(for example I want to know if url on my action object contains confluence then `confluence` else if it contains jira then `jira` on th:text)

```
<p th:text="((${#strings.contains({action.url},'confluence')}) ? 'confluence' : ((${#strings.contains({action.url},'jira')}) ? 'jira' : '')) " />
```

It works.

Comment: This is a very nice implementation and solved my problem, however, the brackets which cover action.url should be removed. The corrected version is:
<p th:text="((${#strings.contains(action.url,'confluence')}) ? 'confluence' : ((${#strings.contains(action.url,'jira')}) ? 'jira' : '')) " />

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have only one element the option is to make multiple conditions.
It is confusing a little bit but if you understanda the logic it is not a big deal.

Lets say you want to do something like this:

```
if(user.role.admin){
 //add only class='text-success'
}else if(user.role.user){
 //add only class='text-primary'
}else{
 //add only class='text-warning'
}
```

The logic is `if1 : 'text-success' ? if2 : 'text-primary' ? 'text-warning'`
Very simple. But the syntax would be like this:

```
<span th:class="( ${user.role.admin} ? 'text-success' : ( ${user.role.user} ? 'text-primary' : 'text-warning' ) )"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that too

```
<p th:if="${projects != null and projects.size() gt 0}"> <a th:href="@{/hire/invite/} + ${f.id}" class="btn waves-effect">Anything</a> </p>
```

Otherthing