# Thymeleaf: how to make table with different colors

Tags: java, html, css, thymeleaf

Could somebody say how to make table with different colors using Thymeleaf? I have a list of events with integer value of risk weight. And I need to colorize the html column (choose  class) by condition. If risk less then 20 is green, if risk from 20 to 50 if yellow, if risk more then 50 is red. How to do several condtions for one ? 
My variant is not working.

```
<td th:text="${data.riskIndex}" th:if="${data.riskIndex &lt; 20 and data.riskIndex &gt;= 0}" class="green"></td>
```

Comment: This thread might be of same value to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561449/how-to-use-thymeleaf-conditions-if-elseif-else

Comment: No, it's not working, because as I understood Thymeleaf have only Elvis operator, and If you have more then 2 conditions it is not cosy. Of course you can use Elvis inside Elvis for 3 conditions. What to do if it more? I could not implement the switch operator for <td> block. I resolved this problem by using JavaScript instead Thymeleaf like this:

Comment: <script>
    var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var z = 0; z < rows.length; z++) {
        if (rows[z].cells[13].innerHTML > 0 && rows[z].cells[13].innerHTML < 20) {
            rows[z].cells[13].style.backgroundColor = "#87ff59";
        } else if (rows[z].cells[13].innerHTML >= 20) {
            rows[z].cells[13].style.backgroundColor = "#ffe75a";
        } //and so on
}
</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case I would use the `th:class` instead of `th:if` (or `th:classappend` if every column shares some additional classes). Inside the `th:class` I would provide a double Elvis operator (unfortunately) to check condition.

```
<td th:text="${data.riskIndex}" th:class="${data.riskIndex lt 20} ? 'green' : (${data.riskIndex le 50} ? 'yellow' : 'red')"></td>
```

Alternatively, when there would be more conditions and you would like not to involve javascript, you can provide some utility method that will convert the `riskIndex` to proper color for you.

E.g. Let say you create a utility class called `DataRepresentationUtils` which contains a method that calculates a proper color for given index:

```
package web.utils;

public class DataRepresentationUtils {

    private DataRepresentationUtils() { }

    public static String convertRiskIndexToRGBLiteral(int riskIndex) {

        // some logic here. Example of output: "#00ff00"

    }
}
```

Then you can use that method inside your template in a following manner:

```
<td th:text="${data.riskIndex}" th:styleappend="'background-color: ' + ${T(web.utils.DataRepresentationUtils).convertRiskIndexToRGBLiteral(data.riskIndex)} + ';'"></td>
```

Comment: Thank you. As a variant. But I tryed to prevent from double or triple Elvis. Particaly done with Thymeleaf (for color background in conddition), particalty with JS (for icons instead text). Like this:

Comment: <div th:if="${data.riskIndex lt 20}"><td class="success" th:text="${data.riskIndex}">riskIndex</td>
</div><div th:if="${data.riskIndex ge 20 and data.riskIndex lt 100}">
<td class="warning" th:text="${data.riskIndex}">riskIndex</td>
 </div>
<div th:if="${data.riskIndex ge 100}">
<td class="danger" th:text="${data.riskIndex}">riskIndex</td>
/div>